# Self-coupling Higgs boson and composite Higgs models

Tags: higgs, electroweak

I'm currently doing my Bachelor Thesis about the Higgs boson and I've read that there are new models which describe the Electroweak Symmetry Breaking considering the Higgs boson as a composite particle.

I was wondering if any of you guys know anything about this topic: how is the current experimental and theoretical status of this kind of research.

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! I'm afraid that "tell me anything you know about this" is a rather vague and broad question - we prefer questions to be more specific. Could you try to narrow down the question, e.g. by specifying the exact models you're interested in, indicating what you've already read and perhaps choosing to ask *either* about the experimental *or* the theoretical status? Don't hesitate to ask e.g. three separate and specific questions instead of a single vague one!

Comment: If I were you, I'd search scholar.google.com for your keywords & click PDF results (which are especially unlikely to be behind a paywall). ArXiv is helpful too.